# How to do deep _.omitby using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

My code:

```js
let obj = {
  x: {
    a: false,
    b: 2,
    c: ''
  },
  y: ''
}

let result = _.omitBy(obj, (value, key) => {
  if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') {
    return key;
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

output: { x: { a: false, b:2, c:''}}

Expected result: {x: {a: false, b:2}}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using lodash. You can get the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) all the items with [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. Then use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert the filtered `entries` back into an object. If the `value` is an `object`, then recursively call the `removeFalsy` function to remove falsy values in the nested object. This works for any level of nesting

```js
function removeFalsy(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "object")
    return Object.entries(obj)
                  .filter(([k, v]) => ![undefined, null, ''].includes(v))
                  .reduce((r, [key, value]) => ({ ...r, [key]: removeFalsy(value) }), {})
  else
    return obj
}

let obj = {
  x: {
    a: false,
    b: 2,
    c: null
  },
  y: ''
}

console.log(removeFalsy(obj))
```

Comment: i dont want remove key with false value

Comment: @rudani.c Now it only filters out `undefined`, `null` and `''`

Comment: Thanks. but, I'm using ES5 and getting Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' error. i think i need to look for another way