# Use lodash to remove nodes from a deeply nested object array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am very new to lodash and I have been searching all over the web but cannot seem to word my search in a way that yields something in the neighborhood of what I need.

What I have a deeply nested array that resembles something like this:

```
[{
   "id": 1,
   "user": "bob",
   "data": {
      "A1": {
            "index": "01",
            "question":[{
               "index": "01.a",
               "isModified": false
            }],
            "sections": [{
               "index": "01.01",
               "question":[{
                  "id": 10,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 20,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 30,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 40,
                  "isModified": true
               }]
            }]
         },
      "A2": {
            "index": "02",
            "question": [{}],
            "sections": [{
               "index": "02.01",
               "question":[{
                  "id": 10,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 20,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 30,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 40,
                  "isModified": false
               }]
            }]
         },
      "A3": {
            "index": "03",
            "question": [{}],
            "sections": [{
               "index": "03.01",
               "question":[{
                  "id": 10,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 20,
                  "isModified": true
               },{
                  "id": 30,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 40,
                  "isModified": true
               }]
            }]
         },
      "A4": {
            "index": "04",
            "question": [{
               "index": "01.a",
               "isModified": true
            }],
            "sections": [{
               "index": "04.01",
               "question":[{
                  "id": 10,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 20,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 30,
                  "isModified": false
               },{
                  "id": 40,
                  "isModified": false
               }]
            }]
         }
   }
}]
```

What I need is to essentially prune the object based on the "isModified" property. I need remove the object if the flag is set to '''false'''. So the resulting object should look like:

```
[{
   "id": 1,
   "user": "bob",
   "data": {
      "A1": {
            "index": "01",
            "question":[{}],
            "sections": [{
               "index": "01.01",
               "question":[{
                  "id": 40,
                  "isModified": true
               }]
            }]
         },
      "A2": {},
      "A3": {
            "index": "03",
            "question": [{}],
            "sections": [{
               "index": "03.01",
               "question":[{
                  "id": 20,
                  "isModified": true
               },{
                  "id": 40,
                  "isModified": true
               }]
            }]
         },
      "A4": {
            "index": "04",
            "question": [{
               "index": "01.a",
               "isModified": true
            }],
            "sections": [{}]
         }
   }
}]
```

I have been trying to get _.filter and _.map to work but they always so to give just the key, value pair and not the actual object. As I said I am new to lodash and this seems like it should be kind of straight forward but I am clearly missing something.

If more information is need to explain what is desired please let me know and I will update the question.

Thanks,
JM

Comment: There’s a lot of ways this could be done; you basically want a deep omitBy, but only questions. It’s a relatively straight-forward recursive process that could be done in vanilla JS, but questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/55146456/438992 and its dupe may help—but you’ll need to also make sure you’re only removing items that **have** that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can map/filter the entries of an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) together. First, you get the entries of an object, then you map/filter those entries, then you build a new object out of the filtered list.

For example, to filter out some values:

```js
const myObject = { car: 1, bike: 2, shovel: 3, card: 4 };
console.log('original:', myObject);

const evensOnly = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(myObject).filter((entry) => {
        return entry[1] % 2 === 0;
    }),
);
// evensOnly is { bike: 2, card: 4 }
console.log('evensOnly:', evensOnly);

const plusOne = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(myObject).map((entry) => {
        return [entry[0], entry[1] + 1];
    }),
);
// plusOne is { car: 2, bike: 3, shovel: 4, card: 5 }
console.log('plusOne:', plusOne);
```

You can apply this to your specific problem by doing something similar to the following (except this code doesn't exactly match your desired output):

```js
const output = input.map((userData) => {
    return {
        id: userData.id,
        user: userData.user,
        data: Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(userData.data).map((dataEntry) => {
                const dataKey = dataEntry[0];
                const dataValue = dataEntry[1];
                dataValue.question = dataValue.question.filter(
                    (questionItem) => {
                        return questionItem.isModified;
                    },
                );
                dataValue.sections = dataValue.sections.map(
                    (sectionItem) => {
                        return {
                            index: sectionItem.index,
                            question: sectionItem.question.filter(
                                (question) => {
                                    return question.isModified;
                                },
                            ),
                        };
                    },
                );
                return [dataKey, dataValue];
            }),
        ),
    };
});
```

You will have to tweak it to get the results you want, but this should be a good example you can work from.

Comment: This seems interesting and i will look into it; however it does not seem very flexible. If properties are added in the future the code would need to be updated every time. perhaps unavoidable but was looking for something a bit more generic/dynamic

Comment: Unfortunately, dealing with deeply-nested objects can get tricky and specific. If you're concerned about extensibility, I suggest breaking the code into smaller functions. For example, you could make a function that just filters out values from the `question` type object and another function that just filters out from the `solution` type object. Then you can combine these functions in a more modular way. Best of luck with your particular situation :)

Comment: Even though the code i ended up with was very differentl I am accepting your answer as it pointed me in the right direction and provided a good basis for the final code. cheers mate.